# Terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos7

I'm trying to upgrade rails version in my ruby project from rails 6 to rails 6.1.7. After fixing rails version in Gemfile "gem 'rails', '6.0.0' to gem 'rails', '6.1.7'", i deleted Gemfile.lock and ran the command "bundle install" but it didn't see the executable. Due to a long wait, I pressed "Ctrl + C" and saw the following error::

```
[root@0b2784b4e7bc project]# bundle install
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
Fetching https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack.git




^C#<Thread:0x0000000002fb93c8@/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:287 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from /opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:287:in `block (2 levels) in capture3'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:287:in `read': stream closed in another thread (IOError)
#<Thread:0x0000000002fb9288@/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:288 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from /opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:288:in `block (2 levels) in capture3'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:288:in `read': stream closed in another thread (IOError)
```

I'm not sure why this error and how to fix it? I also tried to search google but maybe my search skills are weak so I couldn't find a similar case. Who can help me in this case?
Thanks very much!

I tried installing ruby on verion 2.7.0 and the error still occurs:

```
[root@0b2784b4e7bc project]# bundle
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
Fetching https://github.com/railsconfig/config.git
^C#<Thread:0x0000000001d50f10 /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open3.rb:287 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open3.rb:287:in `block (2 levels) in capture3'
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open3.rb:287:in `read': stream closed in another thread (IOError)
#<Thread:0x0000000001d50df8 /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open3.rb:288 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open3.rb:288:in `block (2 levels) in capture3'
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open3.rb:288:in `read': stream closed in another thread (IOError)
```

I run *bundle install* and add the *--verbose* option and get the following error:

```
[root@0b2784b4e7bc project]# bundle install --verbose
Running `bundle install --verbose` with bundler 2.3.24
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
Found changes from the lockfile, re-resolving dependencies because the dependencies in your gemfile changed, you added a new platform to your gemfile
Fetching https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack.git


^C
^C
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:298:in `value'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:298:in `block in capture3'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:219:in `popen_run'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:101:in `popen3'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:281:in `capture3'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:236:in `capture_and_filter_stderr'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:167:in `block in git'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:70:in `with_clean_git_env'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:166:in `git'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:159:in `block in git_retry'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/retry.rb:40:in `run'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/retry.rb:30:in `attempt'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:158:in `git_retry'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:98:in `checkout'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/git.rb:326:in `fetch'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/git.rb:172:in `specs'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source.rb:58:in `spec_names'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source_map.rb:21:in `block in all_requirements'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source_map.rb:20:in `map'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source_map.rb:20:in `all_requirements'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:799:in `source_requirements'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:477:in `resolver'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:279:in `resolve'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `resolve_remotely!'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/installer.rb:271:in `resolve_if_needed'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/installer.rb:82:in `block in run'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/process_lock.rb:12:in `block in lock'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in `open'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in `lock'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/installer.rb:71:in `run'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/installer.rb:23:in `install'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/cli/install.rb:62:in `run'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/cli.rb:257:in `block in install'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/settings.rb:131:in `temporary'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/cli.rb:256:in `install'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.24/exe/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:120:in `with_friendly_errors'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.24/exe/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
#<Thread:0x0000000002784c48@/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:287 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from /opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:287:in `block (2 levels) in capture3'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:287:in `read': stream closed in another thread (IOError)
#<Thread:0x0000000002784b08@/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:288 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from /opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:288:in `block (2 levels) in capture3'
/opt/todomail/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:288:in `read': stream closed in another thread (IOError)
```

Comment: I guess the most important info is right at the top: _Don't run Bundler as root._. Did you try to install Ruby, Bundler and all the gems as a normal user?

Comment: @spickermann I haven't tried the user yet, but I think it's not related to the root account warning. Because if I set rails to version 6 and don't delete Gemfile.lock, it still runs bundle install normally

Comment: I don't know what causes the error yet. But running _bundle install rails_ fixed my problem